# Json4s: raw json value

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have very dynamic protocol with web service and I need to store raw JSON value in order to store complete response.

I am using scala and json4s.

```
case class DataClass(value: JValue)
case class Response(status: String, data: DataClass)
```

After parsing

```
{
  "status": "awesome",
  "data": {
    "name": "John",
    "age" : 20
  }
}
```

But in this way, json4s always returns `JNothing`.

```
JsonMethods.parse(json).extract[Response]
```

returns

> Response(awesome,DataClass(JNothing))

Comment: It look very obvious. Your DataClass case class not matching the structure of actual data

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
// case class DataClass(value: JValue)
case class DataClass(name: String, age: Int)
case class Response(status: String, data: DataClass)

val s = """{
  "status": "awesome",
  "data": {
    "name": "John",
    "age" : 20
  }
}"""
val json = parse(s).extract[Response] // json: Response = Response(awesome,DataClass(John,20))
```

You should have your case classes match your json string. In this case, there is no "value" in json string, only "name" and "age". Use "name" and "age" in case class solves the problem.